# Linq data fetch in wcf test client

Tags: web-services, wcf, visual-studio-2012

Here is my query :

```
select * 
from menu
```

I am using wcf web services and i have created local database.

I want to return data using linq and show table's data in wcf client.

Can anyone help me with the function?

Here is my code :

```
namespace CrossDine
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        string connectionString = ...;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }

        public CompositeType GetDataUsingDataContract(CompositeType composite)
        {
            if (composite == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("composite");
            }
            if (composite.BoolValue)
            {
                composite.StringValue += "Suffix";
            }
            return composite;
        }

        public DataTable GetMenu()
        {
           DataTable datatab = null;

           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Menu",con);
           con.Open();

           SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

           da.Fill(datatab);

           return datatab;
        }
    }
}
```

Here Instead of Datatable I want to use linq to return data.

Comment: what you mean saying data in format of linq? Linq is used to query objects and not for formatting data responses.

Comment: sorry my mistake. Using linq not in the format of linq

Comment: no problem. How do you access your database in your service? Are you using an ORM like entity framework? Are you using ADO.NET?

Comment: yes. I am using ADO.Net

Comment: could you please the post all your code and state exactly you want to return?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49141/discussion-between-christos-paisios-and-jay)